# Reading Json Data in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have this Json data returning from a service.

here is my complete json data

```
 d: "[{"ImagePath":null,"ThemeTemplateId":1,"BorderWidth":null,"BorderStyle":null,"OptionTextUnderline":null,"OptionTextItalic":null,"OptionTextBold":null,"OptionTextSize":null,"OptionTextFont":null,"QuestionTextUnderline":null,"QuestionTextItalic":null,"QuestionTextBold":null,"QuestionTextSize":null,"QuestionTextFont":null,"SurveyTitleUnderline":null,"SurveyTitleItalic":null,"SurveyTitleBold":null,"SurveyTitleSize":null,"SurveyTitleFont":null,"BorderColor":null,"SurveyTitleColor":null,"OptionTextColor":null,"ThemeName":null,"BackgroundColor":null,"QuestionTextColor":null},{"ImagePath":null,"ThemeTemplateId":2,"BorderWidth":null,"BorderStyle":null,"OptionTextUnderline":null,"OptionTextItalic":null,"OptionTextBold":null,"OptionTextSize":null,"OptionTextFont":null,"QuestionTextUnderline":null,"QuestionTextItalic":null,"QuestionTextBold":null,"QuestionTextSize":null,"QuestionTextFont":null,"SurveyTitleUnderline":null,"SurveyTitleItalic":null,"SurveyTitleBold":null,"SurveyTitleSize":null,"SurveyTitleFont":null,"BorderColor":null,"SurveyTitleColor":null,"OptionTextColor":null,"ThemeName":null,"BackgroundColor":null,"QuestionTextColor":null}]"
```

///ajax function

```
   jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "3.aspx/GetThemeList",
        data: "{'clientid':'" + -1 + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (returndata) {
            console.log(returndata);
            jQuery.each(returndata, function (index, theme) {
                alert(theme.ImagePath);
                alert(theme.ThemeTemplateId);
            });
        }
    });
```

but its not working for me is there any other method to read this data through jquery.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What is `d` in `returndata`? You don't show that in your example JSON. And have you specified a JSON data type or used `getJSON` since it doesn't look like you're parsing the string into JSON yourself?

Comment: Can you show the complete ajax function ? You need to parse it if you are not setting a `json` datatype.

Comment: edited with complete json data and ajax function.

Answer (score 1):

I think Its working http://jsfiddle.net/SrsxA/2/...

but in you post you missed a comma(`,`) for second JSON object

```
 [{"ImagePath":null,"ThemeTemplateId":1},{"ImagePath":null, "ThemeTemplateId":2}]

                                                           ^-- need comma here
```

#### According to edit

```
d: "[{"Ima..

   ^--- you don't need `"` here and at last, don't need to wrap with `""`.
```

**Full Working code:**

```
var themelist = {
    d: [{
        "ImagePath": 'a',
        "ThemeTemplateId": 1,
        "BorderWidth": null,
        "BorderStyle": null,
        "OptionTextUnderline": null,
        "OptionTextItalic": null,
        "OptionTextBold": null,
        "OptionTextSize": null,
        "OptionTextFont": null,
        "QuestionTextUnderline": null,
        "QuestionTextItalic": null,
        "QuestionTextBold": null,
        "QuestionTextSize": null,
        "QuestionTextFont": null,
        "SurveyTitleUnderline": null,
        "SurveyTitleItalic": null,
        "SurveyTitleBold": null,
        "SurveyTitleSize": null,
        "SurveyTitleFont": null,
        "BorderColor": null,
        "SurveyTitleColor": null,
        "OptionTextColor": null,
        "ThemeName": null,
        "BackgroundColor": null,
        "QuestionTextColor": null},
    {
        "ImagePath": 'b',
        "ThemeTemplateId": 2,
        "BorderWidth": null,
        "BorderStyle": null,
        "OptionTextUnderline": null,
        "OptionTextItalic": null,
        "OptionTextBold": null,
        "OptionTextSize": null,
        "OptionTextFont": null,
        "QuestionTextUnderline": null,
        "QuestionTextItalic": null,
        "QuestionTextBold": null,
        "QuestionTextSize": null,
        "QuestionTextFont": null,
        "SurveyTitleUnderline": null,
        "SurveyTitleItalic": null,
        "SurveyTitleBold": null,
        "SurveyTitleSize": null,
        "SurveyTitleFont": null,
        "BorderColor": null,
        "SurveyTitleColor": null,
        "OptionTextColor": null,
        "ThemeName": null,
        "BackgroundColor": null,
        "QuestionTextColor": null}]
};

$.each(themelist.d, function(index, theme) {
    console.log(theme['ImagePath']);
    console.log(theme.ImagePath);
});
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not contain the same code as the OP. You've missed out the `var themelist = returndata.d;` which may well be part of the problem.

Comment: @FahimParkar - I didn't say it wasn't! That part of the answer is perfectly valid.

Comment: I missed the , in the post. Now i edited with complted json data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
success: function (returndata) {

    // objectify it, if not already
    returndata = (typeof returndata == 'string') ? JSON.parse(returndata) : returndata;

    var themelist = returndata.d;

    .... // rest of your code

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im usualy use this code, working just fine. I set a data array with boolean check `$data["result"] = false` and the `json` values. If true then return `json object` `$data["arrayfrombackendcode"]`

```
success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
     for(var i = 0, var; var= data.arrayfrombackendcode[i]; i++) {
         data.id
         data.name
         etc
     }
},
```

Hope the answer helps

Answer (score 0):

Is that really how the JSON string is encoded?
seems that you opened the string with a quotation mark: `"` instead of an apostrophe `'`